# Does persuading someone while they're charmed last after the charm effect ends?

Tags: dnd-5e, charmed

If my warlock persuades someone to do something while they are charmed with Fey Presence, would they still carry it out when the charmed effect ends?

Answer (score 8):

The charm ending shouldn't affect whether they do what you persuaded them to. Fey Presence only inflicts the Charmed condition, which in turn does this:

> The charmer has advantage on any ability check to interact socially with the creature.

In other words, while charmed, they are particularly receptive to persuasion from you. So persuading them to do something while charmed is no different to persuading them to do something normally. Them being charmed just makes it easier.

So, just like if you'd persuaded them to do something without any magic being involved, they probably won't change their mind without some reason, but there's nothing *stopping* them from changing their mind. [As a famous rogue once said](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0768.html), the magic is in your words, not in their belief.

Answer (score 0):

### It's up to your DM, and the answer will probably vary

The Charmed condition has only two effects: the charmed can't attack the charmer, and (PHB 290):

> The charmer has advantage on any ability check to interact socially with the creature.

Unlike Domination, nothing about being charmed requires the charmed creature to do anything, whether they're charmed or not. It will be up to the creature, and therefore your DM, to decide if they're going to stick to their word.

For example, if a creature figures out that they were charmed into doing something they didn't want to do, they would probably stop, whereas a creature that only needed a little persuasion might go along with you anyway.